# Dispaying and editing a sub property of a property in PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, propertygrid

I could no longer find an exact solution to my problem in the internet so I'm asking this question. Hope you may be able to help me.

I have the following classes:

```
public Item 
{
    public FieldType MyField { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Capacity { get; set; }
}

public FieldType 
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string FieldCode { get; set; }
    public string TableCode { get; set; }
}
```

In my form, I created an instance of Item class. Which contains the following members:

- MyField (type of FieldType)
- Description (type of string)
- Capacity (an int)

Is it possible to only show the `Value` member of `MyField` property in the `PropertyGrid`?

Below is how I assign the selected object property of the `PropertyGrid`.

```
void Form1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = new Item();          
}
```

Comment: You can control what and how is displayed by creating a wrapper. Typical application is to translate all properties, hide some, run-time switching, etc. But the very basic answer is to use `[Browsable(false)]` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, easy:
add a computed read only property to `Item`

```
public Item 
{
   public FieldType MyField { get; set; }
   public string MyFieldValue => MyField.Value;
   public string Description { get; set; }
   public int Capacity { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1 - Add a property**

You can add a property to `Item` class to get and set `MyField.Value`:

```
public string Value
{
    get
    {
        if (MyField != null)
            return MyField.Value;
        return null;
    }
    set
    {
        if (MyField != null)
            MyField.Value = value;
    }
}
```

[image]

• Preferably define that property in a partial class.
• Use this option when you have access to codes of the classes. If those classes are not yours, use 3rd solution.

**Solution 2 - Use ExpandableObjectConverter**

You can decorate the `MyField` property of `Item` class with `ExpandableObjectConverter`. Also decorate `FieldType` with `[Browsable(false)]` of `FieldType` class to hide it in property grid if you want:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
public FieldType MyField { get; set; }
```

[image]

• To customize the text which is shown in front of `MyField`, you can override `ToString` method of `FieldType` and return `Value`. Also you can do it using a custom `TypeConverter` and overriding its `ConvertTo` method.

**Solution 3 - Use a custom TypeDescriptor**

It's not as easy as the first solution, but the output is completely like what you get using the first solution. It's suitable for cases that you can not manipulate those classes.

You can use it this way:

```
var item = new Item() { MyField = new FieldType() { Value = "Some Value" } };
TypeDescriptor.AddProvider(new MyTypeDescriptionProvider(), item);
this.propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = item;
```

Or by decorating `Item` class with:

```
[TypeDescriptionProvider(typeof(MyTypeDescriptionProvider))]
public class Item
```

*Custom Property Descriptor*

```
public class MyPropertyDescriptor : PropertyDescriptor
{
    private PropertyDescriptor subProperty;
    private PropertyDescriptor parentProperty;
    public MyPropertyDescriptor(PropertyDescriptor parent, PropertyDescriptor sub)
        : base(sub, null)
    {
        subProperty = sub;
        parentProperty = parent;
    }
    public override bool IsReadOnly { get { return subProperty.IsReadOnly; } }
    public override void ResetValue(object component)
    {
        subProperty.ResetValue(parentProperty.GetValue(component));
    }
    public override bool CanResetValue(object component)
    {
        return subProperty.CanResetValue(parentProperty.GetValue(component));
    }
    public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component)
    {
        return subProperty.ShouldSerializeValue(parentProperty.GetValue(component));
    }
    public override Type ComponentType { get { return parentProperty.ComponentType; } }
    public override Type PropertyType { get { return subProperty.PropertyType; } }
    public override object GetValue(object component)
    {
        return subProperty.GetValue(parentProperty.GetValue(component));
    }
    public override void SetValue(object component, object value)
    {
        subProperty.SetValue(parentProperty.GetValue(component), value);
        OnValueChanged(component, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

*Custom type Descriptor*

```
public class MyTypeDescriptor : CustomTypeDescriptor
{
    ICustomTypeDescriptor original;
    public MyTypeDescriptor(ICustomTypeDescriptor originalDescriptor)
        : base(originalDescriptor)
    {
        original = originalDescriptor;
    }
    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties()
    {
        return this.GetProperties(new Attribute[] { });
    }
    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        var properties = original.GetProperties().Cast<PropertyDescriptor>().ToList();
        var parent = properties.Where(x => x.Name == "MyField").First();
        var sub = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(FieldType))["Value"];
        properties.Remove(parent);
        properties.Add(new MyPropertyDescriptor(parent, sub));
        return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(properties.ToArray());
    }
}
```

*Custom TypeDescriptorProvider*

```
public class MyTypeDescriptionProvider : TypeDescriptionProvider
{
    public MyTypeDescriptionProvider()
        : base(TypeDescriptor.GetProvider(typeof(object))) { }

    public override ICustomTypeDescriptor GetTypeDescriptor(Type objectType,
                                                            object instance)
    {
        ICustomTypeDescriptor baseDes = base.GetTypeDescriptor(objectType, instance);
        return new MyTypeDescriptor(baseDes);
    }
}
```

• Use this option if `Item` and `FieldType` are not yours. If those classes are yours and you can change their code, use first solution.

Comment: If anyone uses Method 2 with the ExpandableObjectConverter and the parent class has a ToString() method to show values from the child properties, to get it to refresh in the propertygrid, you can add an attribute [NotifyParentProperty(true)] to each property that is part of the ToString().

Answer (score 0):

Im not really sure of what you are looking for but here are 2 answers
1.(as I understood it)
if you want it to show only `Value` when you try and view the properties of a `MyField` Instance then all you need to do is add a constructor to the `MyField` so you can assign the other two values and change the public property to `private` like so

```
public FieldType 
{
   public string Value { get; set; }
   private string FieldCode { get; set; }
   private string TableCode { get; set; }
}
```

2.(this will hide the `MyField` from your propertyGrid)
Override the `ToString()` method of `FielType`
like so

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return Value;
}
```

then set your `MyField` to private and encapsulate it. returning the instance as a string. which would use the overridden value.
like so

```
private FieldType MyField;
public string value{ get{return MyField.ToString();}set;}
```

your MyField will return the overridden `ToString` value which returns Value.

Comment: 'public string value{ get{return MyField;}set;}' - I think this will cause a compile time error